# Draw graphs using Networkx to_agraph()

Tags: python, networkx

I have a networkx digraph object. I can draw the graph in a file using to_agraph. But I want to draw the graph in memory, something that I can then save in a database table, without necessarily writing it to a file. Is there a way to do so?

Following is the code that I use to draw my graph to a file.

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(MyNodes)
g.add_add_edges_from(MyEdges)
grph=nx.to_agraph(g)
s=grph.string()
grph.layout(prog='dot')
grph.draw('test_graph.gif')
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a file you will get a string with the image data.
e.g.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G=nx.path_graph(4)

In [3]: A=nx.to_agraph(G)

In [4]: A.layout(prog='dot')

In [5]: png=A.draw(format='png')

In [6]: png[0:10]
Out[6]: '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Thank you @Aric, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if we can generate a thumbnail instead of huge graph images? Thanks again.

Comment: You could try using PIL.  The example on http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm of 'Reading from a string' shows how to read the string 'png' above into a image object that you can manipulate.